# Is there a better way to implement a hook that delays updating the data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to make a custom hook that updates my data on a delay when a state value changes. This was the only way I found to get it to work how I wanted to.  The problem I had was the onUpdate would always cause the useEffect to fire. So I used useRef to control exactly when to run onUpdate.

Is there a better way to implement a hook like this? I feel like I'm not supposed to use useRef in this way?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useDebounce = (value, delay, onUpdate) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  const shouldUpdate = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
      shouldUpdate.current = true;
    }, delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, [value, delay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldUpdate.current) {
      onUpdate(debouncedValue);
      shouldUpdate.current = false;
    }
  }, [debouncedValue, onUpdate]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

export default useDebounce;
```

Comment: I don't understand why the 2nd `useEffect`. Have you checked this one? https://github.com/uidotdev/usehooks/blob/main/index.js#L225

Comment: Because I want to run the onUpdate whenever it changes.

Comment: Why not just run it after `setDebouncedValue(value)`?

Comment: When I did that, it continually ran onUpdate on a loop due to onUpdate being in that useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: @sketchrandal900 You could use a generic delay function like this: https://tsplay.dev/Wvxn4N

Comment: I think your problem might reside outside the hook if adding `onUpdate` to the dependency array generates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, instead of using `useRef` you can use the combination of `useState` and `useEffect` to track the debounced value and trigger the `onUpdate` function.

sample code :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useDebounce = (value, delay, onUpdate) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, [value, delay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedValue !== value) {
      onUpdate(debouncedValue);
    }
  }, [debouncedValue, value, onUpdate]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

export default useDebounce;
```